# Erro no projeto Missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

Boa tarde, estou com um problema no meu projeto e não fui capaz de descobrir o que o está causando o problema. Qualquer ajuda é apreciada.

```
function logOnConsole(newLog) {
currDate = new Date();
currHour = parseInt(currDate.getHours());
currMin = parseInt(currDate.getMinutes());

if(currHour < 10) {
currHourStr = "0" + currHour;
} else {
currHourStr = "" + currHour;
}

if(currMin < 10) {
currMinStr = "0" + currMin;
} else {
currMinStr = "" + currMin;
}
if(logStack == 10) {
    shiftLog("[" + currHourStr + ":" + currMinStr + "]  " + newLog);
} else {
    setLogStr("[" + currHourStr + ":" + currMinStr "]  " + newLog, 
logStack + 1);
    logStack++;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na **linha 20**, você não concatena o fechamento dos colchetes.

Substitua

```
setLogStr("[" + currHourStr + ":" + currMinStr "]  " + newLog,
  logStack + 1);
//                                            ^
//                                            |
//                                           aqui
```

por:

```
setLogStr("[" + currHourStr + ":" + currMinStr + "]  " + newLog,
  logStack + 1);
```

Comment: Obrigado, distração minha.

Comment: @GabrielC. de nada! Abraços